# Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-6.noarch (/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch) - Requires: /etc/redhat-release

Tags: postgresql, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, postgres-10

This is a DockerFile. Facing issue on Mac.

```
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-6.noarch (/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch)
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y     https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please check below Dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.5

RUN yum install -y \
    https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm
RUN sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-6.9-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-10-redhat.repo"
RUN yum install -y postgresql10-devel
RUN gem update bundler

CMD "/bin/bash"
```

Please provide solutions for Mac. I tried all other similar question answers but nothing worked for me so posted it again.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. This seems to be a non-programming related docker question that then belongs to https://superuser.com

Comment: I am trying to create a docker image with this Dockerfile on mac but I am facing this issue

Comment: ...and it's not a programming issue, is it? Still in the wrong place

Comment: No it is not a programming issue. It is a docker issue for Mac